# Configure Swagger UI to accept a map in Spring boot microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I've created an api that takes in a map of values (filters, sorting, pagination etc,) from UI as below:

```
/**
     * Retrieves audit records for events
     *
     * @param allRequestParams filters
     * @return search results with list of {@link Event}
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve audit records for events")
    @GetMapping("/audit")
    public ResponseEntity getAuditRecords(
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams
    ) throws PermissionsDeniedException, GenericException, GeneralSecurityException {
        log.info("Retrieving audit records of all events...");
        List<Event> events = eventService.getAuditRecords(userPrincipleService.getUserPrinciple(), allRequestParams);

        if (isEmpty(events)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(getPaginatedResponse(allRequestParams, events), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here I'm capturing all the information from UI in a map:

```
@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams
```

This is the actual request from UI:

```
https://<base-url>/api/contract/restructure-event/audit?cb=1622617155911&page=0&size=20&fromDate=2021-06-02T23:00:00.000Z
```

But when I look into the swagger docs, it looks like this:
[image]

which makes it impossible to test.

Is there any way that I can provide the map values via Swagger UI in a human readable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ApiImplicitParam](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html#:%7E:text=Annotation%20Type%20ApiImplicitParam&text=Represents%20a%20single%20parameter%20in,non%2DJAX%2DRS%20environments.) allows you to manually define a parameter in a fine-tuned manner.

Ex: I have defined two example parameters from your actual request(page & size)...

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve audit records for events")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", value = "enter page value.", dataTypeClass = Integer.class, paramType = "query")
        ,@ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", value = "enter size value.", dataTypeClass = Integer.class, paramType = "query")
    })
    @GetMapping("/audit")
    public ResponseEntity getAuditRecords(
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams
    ) throws PermissionsDeniedException, GenericException, GeneralSecurityException {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This resolved the problem almost 100%. However, I still see the old map parameter and i have to enter a random value in order to make an api request successfully.

Comment: If you want to hide the old map parameter in endpoint, you can add @ApiIgnore to this parameter as `@ApiIgnore @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allRequestParams`.